# When was the first dementor created and by whom?

Tags: harry-potter, dementors

I'm unable to figure out when was the first Dementor created and by whom. I know they don't breed and grow out of despair and gloom and they can't be destroyed. They have been guarding Prison of Azkaban since long time but where did they come from or who created them for the first time?

Comment: Related: [How are Dementors created/born?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/8919/31394) and [Did Ekrizdis create the Dementors?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/120595/31394)

Comment: I don't think it is the same question. The context is the same but it is not about who did not create them but actually when and who. I want to know if there exists some data about there first appearance